# Update custom column data in default AspNetUsers database table

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-identity

**UPDATE:**

.net 5.0

I added a number of custom columns to my AspNetUsers database. I am now trying to populate these columns from a form I have added to a scaffolded Identity Razor page.

**Expected Behaviour:**

1. Click Submit on Register Page
2. User Created in dbo.AspNetUsers
3. User lands on Register Confirmation Page
4. Click Submit on Register Confirmation Page
5. Custom Value Stored in dbo.AspNetUSers table
6. User redirected to page

**Actual Behaviour:**

1. Click Submit on Register Page
2. User Created in dbo.AspNetUsers
3. User lands on Register Confirmation Page
4. Click Submit on Register Confirmation Page
5. Custom Value is **Not Stored** in dbo.AspNetUSers table
6. User redirected to page

On the Register page I cache the user details so I can find the user in the DB table on the next page

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DateTime SignedUpDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, SignedUp = SignedUpDateTime, TandC = Input.TOSAgree, MarketingComms = Input.MarketingComms };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

            _cache.Set("User", user);

other code goes here...
}
```

Register Confirmation Page I am trying to save the FirstName. The new column already exists in the DB.

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("******************* On Post Async");

        using (ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            ApplicationUser user = (ApplicationUser)_cache.Get("User");
            Debug.WriteLine("******************* user: " + user.ToString());
            var userId = user.Id.ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine("******************* userId: " + userId);

            user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
            Debug.WriteLine("******************* FirstName: " + Input.FirstName);
            var name = dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(n => n.FirstName == Input.FirstName);
            Debug.WriteLine("******************* name: " + name);

            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("******************* Return Page");

        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { culture });
    }
```

**Debug Log Output:**

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executing handler method MyApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterConfirmationModel.OnPostAsync - ModelState is Valid
******************* On Post Async
******************* user: myemail@email.com
******************* userId: e1234567-1234-1234-1234-0bbf3f123456
******************* FirstName: John
******************* name: 
******************* Return Page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out!

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        ApplicationUser user = (ApplicationUser)_cache.Get("User");
        var userId = user.Id.ToString();

        var appUser = await dbContext.Users.FindAsync(userId);
        appUser.FirstName = Input.FirstName;

        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { culture });
}
```